# Linux: count files that contains a word in its name and content

Tags: linux, terminal, find

I want to count files in directory that in its name and content contains a given word.

```
find ./test -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*main*" | wc -l
```

Given snippet counts files that contains "main" in name. How to change it to check if it contains "main" in its content as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your files and use `grep -q` which suppresses grep output:

```
for file in `find ./test -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*main*"`; do
    if grep -q main $file; then
        wc -l $file
    fi
done
```

Output

```
5 ./test/foo_main
```

Answer (score 0):

`find ./test -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*main*" -exec grep -q main {} \; -exec printf '\n' \; | wc -l`

`-exec printf '\n' \;` instead of `-print` protects against filenames with newline characters.